# Logic based on who is the callee

Tags: java, spring, methods, struts2

I have a class X which has say do method.

I have another two classes A & B in which object of X is created.

**Is there any way by which I can find out whether x's do() is getting called by A or B.**

I do not want to use parameter in do() method. Anything from call trace or something?

I am using struts2, Spring. So any help from frameworks???

I want to implement some logic in do() based on whether its called from A or B.

Comment: I think this is a terrible idea in general.  For at least 50 years we have known that programs are more maintainable if subprograms do one job, do it with as few side effects as possible, and do it regardless of who called the subprogram.  (In case you don't know, a method is what we call a subprogram in Java and a few other languages)  

If A and B need different things done, then they should be calling different methods.  If the logic of X.do() depends on which class/method called it, then some of the caller's logic is embedded in the method, hidden from whoever is maintaining the caller.

Comment: Can you provide more specifics as to why you want to do this? This approach seems very brittle (what if there was another class C that called the do method?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand this looks wired but existing logic will can be quickly tweeted to work for this.

The scenario is,

I have two actions A & B which calls the service X.

X is intercepted by Spring AOP to add filters and passed to DAO's.

If A calls X then show all data i.e do not apply filter, if B calls X then show data only of logged in user.

X is already intercepted for adding some other filters, so it will be easy to add one more filter. Also this filter is present centrally so all A's or B's call X and thus X will do the work accordingly.

I found much better way here, have a instance variable inside X and A's instance of X will have value 'a' and so on.

So now I will be able to distinguish between A's call of X and B's call of X.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, you can retrieve the stack with `Thread.getCurrentThread().getStackTrace()` and read the `StackTraceElement`s `getClassName()` and match against A or B. (I'm trying to imagine a scenario where this would be preferable to a param and coming up blank, but YMMV...)

Answer (score 1):

Possible, but if you have to do it it may be worth just having two methods for the separate functionality which call into a single method for the shared part.

```
Ascall(...)
  specialStuffA
  commonCall(...)

Bscall(...)
  specialStuffB
  commonCall(...)

commonCall(...)
  commonStuffAB
```